# Calculo com função com return Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um calculo que adiciona juros de acordo com o número de parcelas, mas ele está retornando o valor errado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Exercicio1</title>

   <script>

    function caculoCompra(total,parcelas){

       var resul=0;
        if(parcelas=1){

            resul+=total*0
        }
        else if(parcelas=2){
            resul+=(total*0.3)/100

        }
        else{

            resul+=(total*0.7)/100
        }
        return resul;
    }

     window.onload = function(){
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.onclick = function (){
        var resp;
        var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
        var parcelas = document.getElementById("parcelas").value;
        resp=caculoCompra(valor,parcelas);
        alert("O valor final é " + resp);
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Exercicio 1</h2>
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="" >
  Informe o valor
  <input name="login" type="text" id="valor" size="15">
  <br>
 Informe o numero de parcelas 
  <input name="senha" type="text" id="parcelas" size="10">
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="button" id="btn" value="OK">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

O valor que esta retornando

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que queira isso:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Exercicio1</title>

   <script>

    function caculoCompra(total,parcelas){

       var resul=total;// Aqui estava resul=0; como você quer o resultado final eu fiz com que a variável resul recebesse o valor total.
        if(parcelas==1){ // Aqui estava parcelas=1, em um if nunca vai ser possível uma variável receber um valor dentro dela,aí deve ser utilizado o "==", que compara.

            resul=total;
        }
        else if(parcelas==2){ // Da mesma forma, estava o "=" troquei por "=="
            resul+=(total*0.3)/100;

        }
        else{

            resul+=(total*0.7)/100;
        }
        return resul;
    }

     window.onload = function(){
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.onclick = function (){
        var resp;
        var valor = parseInt(document.getElementById("valor").value);
        var parcelas = parseInt(document.getElementById("parcelas").value);
        resp=caculoCompra(valor,parcelas);
        alert("O valor final é " + resp);
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Exercicio 1</h2>
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="" >
  Informe o valor
  <input name="login" type="text" id="valor" size="15">
  <br>
 Informe o numero de parcelas 
  <input name="senha" type="text" id="parcelas" size="10">
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="button" id="btn" value="OK">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```